# Can multiple airfields be in the same airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport, airspace

After reading [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11541/65) that a restricted airport caused a strange cutout in Class B, I am wondering if it possible that there are multiple airfields in the same airspace?

If yes, then:

- Which ATC has most authority
- How congestion is handled?

Please note that I am not talking about an airport which is under an outer circular shelf of a Class B or C airport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When there are several airports close to each other, a single ATC, formally known as Terminal Control Center may service all airports. The airspace boundaries and altitudes assigned to a Terminal Control Center, which vary widely from airport to airport, are based on factors such as traffic flows, neighboring airports and terrain.

[London Terminal Control Centre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Terminal_Control_Centre) is an example of a large and complex Terminal Control Center. Its service area is up to 20,000 feet and out to 100 nautical miles. It controls:

- six London airports
- one Royal Air Force station
- provides en-route services to other aircraft that entered its airspace

Another example can be found with [Berlin-Tegel](http://skyvector.com/airport/EDDT/Berlin-Tegel-Airport) and [Berlin-Schönefeld](http://skyvector.com/airport/EDDB/Berlin-Schonefeld-Airport), which have adjacent control zones that share a common boundary west to east and have an overlaying class C TMA airspace up to FL100. Both airports share the same TMA controller/approach sector:
`BREMEN RADAR Approach:    119.62`

[image: CTR Area Berlin]
<sub>*Image Source: www.skyvector.com*</sub>

---

FAA is implementing a new airspace system which will increase efficiencies at metropolitan areas with complex air traffic flows. This system, known as [Next Generation Air Transportation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Generation_Air_Transportation_System) is introducing the concept of a [metroplex](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/snapshots/metroplexes/):

> In FAA parlance, metroplex refers to a system of airports in close
>   proximity and their shared airspace that serve one or more major
>   cities. A metroplex has at least one, but often two or more major
>   commercial airports.

Comment: this is already done in Norcal: https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/snapshots/metroplexes/?locationId=14